# Best Pretter Formatting Structure for Unlocked Package structure

Tags: git, unlocked-package, github

I am moving towards an unlocked package structure on the Org I work on. The instance was inherited and did not have any version control so seems like 2 birds with one stone. I've always used Prettier (in VSCode) myself and am wondering what is the best (and simplest) way to structure it for a team of devs to use considering our move to unlocked packages/github? Initial idea was having a prettierrrc file in each Repo with the specific modifications we want to use (ie. tabWidth: 4) and a package.json file that looks largely like the default one that installs when you create a new SFDX Project. This would be the easiest for the devs as all you need to do is Run Install after cloning a repo. However it seems a bit difficult from a management perspective for myself as i'd need to modify each file (im sure theres an easy way to do this) whenever might want to modify the Prettierrrc and there will be a decent amount of packages.

An alternative might be a global prettierrrc file that the prettier extension can reference. I am going to keep digging but most resources regarding structuring Prettier for a dev team arent salesforce specific and don't consider having many different projects. So wondering if anyone has set this up before and has any advice?